# How to display a post registration welcome message when using both django-registration and django-socialauth?

Tags: django, django-views, django-registration, django-socialauth

This is a pretty trivial question but I must be missing something because I can't come up with a solution I'm happy with.

I'm using two libraries to handle registration, django-registration for the email based registration and django-socialauth for the social based registration, and want to display a welcome message when the user registers for the first time.

My current approach is to have a context processor that checks if the user has registered within the past 2 minutes and if so, updates the request object. This seems inefficient since I'm checking every time when it's only used once.

I tried implementing it using signals but the issue I ran into was that I needed some way to hook into the request but only django-registration passes the request along.

An option I'm contemplating is using the signals to update a record in the database but that seems like overkill for something this simple. Am I missing something obvious?

context_processors.py:

```python
def just_registered(request):
    just_registered = False
    if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.email:
        if request.user.date_joined < datetime.today() + timedelta(minutes=2):
            if 'just_registered' not in request.session:
                just_registered = True
                request.session['just_registered'] = just_registered
    return { 'just_registered' : just_registered }
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use django messages and implement it in your template

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
    {{message}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

.

```
def just_registered(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.user.date_joined < datetime.today() + timedelta(minutes=2):
            messages.info(request, "Welcome")
    return ''
```

user is authenticated is already understood, you don't have to put user email because when you register, the email is required

Comment: No I understand that part. The problem is I don't want to use the just_registered function at all since the check is done for every page load when I should only be doing it once.

Ah thanks for that note on the email - I'm also using similar code for something else where I need an email and if a user signs up using Twitter then the email is not set.

Comment: How would that work? Wrap every view with roughly the same logic as I have in the context processor?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, you want to display a welcome message when the user successfully logs in for the first time (it says register for the first time in your question)? Do they follow an activation link from an email? You could have that emailed link go to a new user version of your landing page.

Otherwise, if you want to use the same page for normal users and people logging in the for the first time, I don't see how you can avoid checking if this is the user's first time logging in. To do that, it seems like using a boolean attrib on the user (or fk'ed to them) that keeps track of whether they have logged in before would be the way to go, instead of looking at how long ago they activated the account (what if they activated 2 days ago but didn't log in?)

Comment: I'm using the basic authentication flow where no activation is required. As part of the flow it also redirects the user to the page they were on before registering automatically so I can't have a separate page that for just-registered users.

I thought about the DB flag but it seems like overkill so I'm trying to avoid it unless necessary.

Comment: I think using django's messaging framework might work, as princess suggested. I don't remember django-registration's views off hand, but you could go into the one a user hits when creating an account (register maybe?) and add a line that adds a welcome message to the user. Then you don't need the just_registered function.

Comment: Problem is I installed the libraries using pip and although I know I can hack around them I want to avoid it if possible. I may end up doing something simple and generating a signal for the social auth app  to have the same format as the registration app.

Comment: you could also fork django-registration on github, make some changes, and then use pip to install that fork

Answer (score 0):

Following from your comment on princesses answer your best bet would be to save some kind of data when the user logs in for the first time.

I would suggest write a simple middleware which detects first login and saves that in a persistent form

Have a look at this:

http://blog.elcodo.pl/post/926902087/django-detect-users-first-login

You can also checkout the middleware in django tracking

https://github.com/codekoala/django-tracking/blob/master/tracking/middleware.py

It is slightly inefficient , however I don't see any other way given the statelessness of HTTP